# How do you Moq a .resx that lives in App_GlobalResource?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, unit-testing, moq, app-globalresources

I'm writing unit tests for a controller in an MVC3 web project, but my tests throw exceptions when they try and access a resource like this:

```
return Index(Resources.Strings.MyStringResource);
```

The resource is a `.resx` file titled `Strings`.

I'm using the [Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/) libraries to achieve unit test for `HttpContextBase` functionality, so I was wondering how I would go about using the Moq libraries to access an App_GlobalResource.

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't, at least not directly.  The strongly-typed classes that are generated from resource (.resx) files expose static, not instance methods.

Because of this, they can't implement an interface method, nor are they virtual; [Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/) requires that at least one of these conditions are met in order to create a mock.

To get around this, you would create an abstraction, like anything else:

```
public interface IResources
{
    string MyStringResource { get; }
}
```

You'd pass (or inject) an implementation of this into your controller, and then pass that to your `Index` method.  That implementation might look something like this:

```
public class ResourcesWrapper : IResources
{
    public string MyStringResource 
    { 
        get 
        { 
            return Resources.Strings.MyStringResource; 
        } 
    }
}
```

Then, when you're testing, you can use Moq to create a mock of the `IResources` interface, and pass that to your controller, like so:

```
// Create the mock.
var mock = new Mock<IResources>();

// Setup the property.
mock.SetupProperty(m => m.MyStringResource, "My Mocked Value");

// Pass the object somewhere for use.
Assert.AreEqual(mock.Object.MyStringResource, "My Mocked Value");
```

Comment: Hi Casper, I've just tried implementing your answer, and it has failed, throwing an `IOException`:
`"Could not load file or assembly 'App_GlobalResources' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.":"App_GlobalResources"`
Can you provide any further tips?

Comment: @MartinBlake That sounds like a separate issue.  Although the class where `ResourcesWrapper` implements `IResources` should exist in the same assembly that the resources are embedded in; those typed wrappers are marked internal.'

Comment: check out my solution below, I'll mark your answer as the accepted one, as I'd have been nowhere without it! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

So, after implementing [casperOne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/50776/casperone)'s answer, I ran into another error:

I was presented with an `IOException` stating:

`"Could not load file or assembly 'App_GlobalResources' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.":"App_GlobalResources"`

**Scott Allen** provided the [reason and inherent solution](http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2009/07/16/resource-files-and-asp-net-mvc-projects.aspx) to this problem.

So what I did was made a new resources file in a new folder named 'TResources' in my web project, named 'TResources' purely because it is a Resources folder that is only being created and used for Testing purposes (clever, eh?)

I then changed the properties of my `ResourcesWrapper` class to return `TResources.Strings.MyStringResource` rather than `Resources.Strings.MyStringResource`.

**NOTE:** The properties in the `IResources` interface **must not be read-only**, as when setting up the mock object, if the property is **read-only** it will fail as the value cannot be set.

Therefore, `IResources` should look a little something like this:

```
public interface IResources
{
    string MyStringResource { get; set; }
}
```

`ResourcesWrapper` should then implement `IResources` like this:

```
public class ResourcesWrapper : IResources
{
    public string MyStringResource 
    { 
        get 
        { 
            return TResources.Strings.MyStringResource; 
        } 
        set
        {
            //do nothing
        }
    }
}
```

So that you can then achieve a successful mock in your Unit Test, like this:

```
var mock = new Mock<IResources>();
mock.SetupProperty(m => m.MyStringResource, "");
```

**NOTE:** You don't have to specify anything in the `initialValue` parameter of the method above, as the property will be returning a value retrieved from the `Strings.resx`.

That concludes my question, I hope this can be helpful to someone else on internet land!

Comment: Why would you add a setter to the interface?  Moq absolutely allows read-only properties to have values set, but you have to call `SetProperty`.  Also, this is a little bit of a separate question and answer, it doesn't directly address the question, as posted.

Comment: Thought I may have posted it in the wrong place. Any tips on where it should go?
And I had created them as read-only properties, but it threw an error, so I just shoved a setter on there. This is only a demo project so I wasn't too worried.

Answer (score 0):

[This response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5402097/335545) to a [similar Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5398196/335545) by [Darin Dimitrov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/29407/darin-dimitrov) provides a much simpler approach. It's all about modifying the Resources.resx file properties to support unit testing.